# Parse a SRV DNS record that was created in djbdns format using python

Tags: python, bash, parsing, dns

I'm parsing an DNS zone file written in TinyDNS format (djbdns) and I'm having problems decoding SRV records.

I'm so far able to parse everything correctly from the SRV record but the answer which contain a set of octal numbers for the priority, weight and port (normal values for a SRV DNS Record) below is an example that can be generated from [here](https://anders.com/projects/sysadmin/djbdnsRecordBuilder/#SRV)

```sh
:_sip._tcp.example.com:33:\000\012\000\144\023\304\003pbx\007example\003com\000:86400
```

The part that I'm having issues is the DNS answer:

```sh
\000\012\000\144\023\304\003pbx\007example\003com\000
```

First 24 chars

```sh
\000\012\000\144\023\304
```

Rest of chars

```sh
\003pbx\007example\003com\000
```

The first 24 chars contains the priority, weight and port of the service that the DNS will be using, from the 24th chart to the end of the string is the target host that is providing the service. So parsing the target is easy, each Octal set before the string is the number of chars to expect between and is removing the  periods.

Priority, Weight and Port accepts values from 0 - 65535  which transforms the the values into 2 sets of 255 i.e \000\144 = 10 decimal but if the number is more than 256 bits then it uses the second set i.e \023\304 = 5060 at this point i'm blocked i have no idea what they are doing, converting each set individually or together is not giving me the right decimal number.  I know i'm close but is super blocked. I'm using the default int method to transform from octal to dec which is fairly easy.

```py
octal = '144'
dec   = int(octal, 8)
```

After I parse it it should be something like this (obviously the spaces is something that I'm doing in my code to concat values.

```
10 100 5060 pbx.example.com
```

Any guidance or hint guys would be appreciated!

Comment: You need to look at the RFC that defines the `SRV` record and its "wire" representation that will explain what bytes you will find, and what they mean. See RFC2782 and how both priority, weight, port are defined as from 0 to 65535 so they take 2 bytes or 16 bits. As for the name, its encoding is explained in core DNS RFC, aka §3.1 of RFC1035. Note also the compression explained later in the document but outside of live DNS packets in the network you shouldn't see the compression case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of \023\304 as high and low parts.
You need to bitshift the high part.

```
>>> high = '023'
>>> low = '304'
>>> high_dec = int(high, 8)
>>> low_dec = int(low, 8)
>>> (high_dec << 8) + low_dec
5060
```

Comment: holy mother of god!!! Highs and lows! Thats right man! Thank you for your help I was blocked for days.

Comment: You're welcome. Bit shifting always comes to mind whenever I see groups of octal numbers. If you're happy with the answer I would appreciate if you could accept it. Trying to build some reputation here!  :) Thank you.